# Files on branch without being merged into it

Tags: git

I am working on a project that has many different branches, one of which is called 'live' which has all of the code that is currently running on a live server. However recently some changes have managed to make their way onto this live branch, without being merged in, from a branch called 'test_theme'.

I have looked through the history of the repository and at no point can I see anything that says that 'test_theme' has been merged into 'live'.

How would one go around trying to find out how these changes managed to make it onto the 'live' branch with out being merged into it?

Comment: Compare the history for the commits on the live. Surely the related test_theme files or code was added at some point...

Comment: They could have been cherry picked in.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout live
git blame file-with-illegal-changes
```

Then look for the lines in question and you will get the commit hash (including timestamp and author) right away.

Comment: There are *many* ways the change could've been introduced without a merge.  (Rebase, cherry-pick, squash merge, manual checkout of affected files (`git checkout test_theme -- file1 file2 ...`), manual re-application of the changes.)  All you can do is look for the commit that introduced the change from `live`'s point of view.  This answer is the most direct way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Choose one of the files that now contains code you don't want.  Run `git log -p THE_FILE`.  This will show you every single change to that file, starting with the most recent.  Page down or search until you see the bad change.  Then look at the commit info displayed above that.  You will see the commit hash where the bad code was introduced.  You can then run `git show -p THE_HASH` to see the full details of that commit, including the timestamp, the author, and any other changes made to other files in that commit.